# Открыть ссылку через главную страницу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

На `index.php`  есть ссылка, которая открывает во всплывающем окне (`fancybox`) `iframe`, в котором `pdf`.

Вот структура ссылки

```
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="pdf/106_spb.pdf">Открыть</a>
```

Как сделать на стороннем ресурсе ссылку так, чтобы она открывалась именно на главной странице, через всплывающее окно, а не просто `pdf` в браузере ?

Comment: Вам надо пересылать на главную страницу с каким-нибудь дополнительным параметром (типа `index.php?show-fancy=true`). А в `index` сделать JS, который при наличии  доп параметра откроет `pdf` так, как Вам надо.

Comment: @cyadvert, Не затруднит ли Вас чуть более подробнее описать решение данной проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На стороннем ресурсе размещаете ссылку на свой `index.php`. К ссылке добавляете параметр, который "скажет" Вашей системе, что надо открыть окно.
Например: `http://www.[ваш-сайт].com/index.php?show-fancy=true`

На самой `index.php` вставляете JS код, который запустится только при наличии `show-fancy=true`.
Например так:

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST["show-fancy"]==true) { ?>
<script>
$.fancybox.open({type:'iframe', href:'pdf/106_spb.pdf'});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Я не уверен насчет кода, запускающего `fancybox`. Это Вам надо будет разобраться самому.